# xml element inserting error with Objective-C garbage collection turned on

Tags: objective-c, xml, cocoa, xcode, garbage-collection

The following piece of code worked fine if garbage collection was not turned on in the project properties option.  But with GC turned on, this is the error message:

"*** Assertion failure in -[NSXMLFidelityElement insertChild:atIndex:], /SourceCache/Foundation/Foundation-751.53/XML.subproj/XMLTypes.subproj/NSXMLElement.m:823"
"Cannot add a child that has a parent; detach or copy first"

Any suggestion?

```
 -(void)insertXmlRecord
{
    //xmlDoc is an iVar
    NSXMLElement *nodeToAdd = [[NSXMLElement alloc] initWithXMLString:[self readOnScreenSetAttrib] error:nil];  
    NSError *err=nil;
    NSXMLElement *thisName;
    NSArray *nodes = [xmlDoc nodesForXPath:@"./dream" error:&err];
    NSLog(@"insertXMLRecord xmldoc %@", xmlDoc);    
    if ([nodes count] > 0 ) 
    {
        thisName = [nodes objectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"insertXMLRecord: thisname: %@", thisName);
        NSLog(@"insertXMLRecord: nodeToAdd: %@", nodeToAdd);
        [thisName addChild:nodeToAdd];
    }
    //NSLog(@"insertXMLRecord");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're seeing that because with GC on, the parent node is seen as "still in use" and so remains attached to its child node. You must copy the child node before adding it to `thisName`:

```
[thisName addChild:[nodeToAdd copy]];
```

Comment: This looks like a bug. Without GC `nodeToAdd` has no parent, with GC it has one... Using `copy` is just circumventing the bug. So, unless I'm completely off base here, I'd recommend you file a bug report with Apple.

Comment: I suspect we don't really have the full code--if the parent is released but the node is retained, it might set its child nodes' parent to `nil`, but since the reference isn't `__weak`, it won't do that in a GC environment.

Comment: I tested it, create an `NSXMLElement` without GC and `parent` returns `nil`, turn on GC and it doesn't...

Comment: Interesting. Since you have a test case, perhaps you should file the bug?

Comment: Hi guys, anyone here can tell me if the bug was filed to apple? Cause i'm facing the same issue in iOS simulator and Xcode 7.1 :/

Answer (score 0):

**it Works for me** thanks *Jonathan Grynspan*

```
 NSDecimalNumber *time = message.time;
    NSXMLElement *timex = [[NSXMLElement alloc] initWithName:@"timex"];
    [timex setStringValue:time.stringValue];
    [timex addChild:[timex copy]];
    [timex addChild:timex];
```

Att. Carlos Ramirez